# Subdomain pointing to another Windows 2012 server + using wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, server, subdomain

I have a main server "domain.com" (let's say 78.125.0.209) and a wildcard SSL certificate for this domain name. I want to use another server's subdirectory (78.125.0.210/subdir/) as a subdomain called "s1.domain.com" and use the wildcard certificate for that server too. Both servers are Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5.

How do I achieve this?

At the moment the SSL certificate works on the main server and I have exported it to the other server as well (not tested though) but I am unable to find the right settings so that typing "s1.domain.com" on a browser would take me to 78.125.0.210/subdir/.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a CNAME or A record DNS entry either for "s1" or "*" that resolves to 78.125.0.210.
2. Create a new IIS site for that machine that tells IIS on that machine that the application is at the desired subfolder.

Comment: I have added Forward Lookup Zone "domain.com" on main server and added there A record "s1" that resolves to 78.125.0.210. There already is a IIS site, but for some reason "s1.domain.com" does not work at all (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED).

Comment: That sounds like a DNS issue.  Can you ping the "s1" server?

Comment: You are right. Pinging does not work and Server Manager (DNS - Events) shows:

"414     Warning     Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service DNS Server
The DNS server computer currently does not have a DNS domain name.  
...
4) Click either Domain or Workgroup, and then type the name of the domain or  workgroup you want the computer to join; the domain or workgroup name will be used as your DNS domain name."

So I need to rename the Workgroup (at Control Panel\System and Security\System) to "domain" to match the domain.com used on the main server?

Comment: Just to clarify, the main server name is at the moment "COMPANY-SRV1" and its Workgroup is called "Workgroup". Is this the problem and if so, do I need to change these on the subdomain server as well? What is the right format to get the above mentioned scenario to work?

Comment: Names and membership in Microsoft Active Directory Services is completely irrelevant.  I'm talking about DNS.  Websites use DNS for name resolution, not MSAD.  If you are using AD-integrated DNS for local DNS (which will only work during testing), each server must also have a distinct name there, or you must use static IP addresses for them and use those in the DNS entries.

Comment: DNS entry for subdomain was static IP but for main server (with the DNS service) I used the defaults given by the Forward Lookup Zone wizard. That's when I got the 414 Warning.

Not sure if this applies here but for similar situation somebody recommends this: https://serverfault.com/a/300955

I don't need to test this for now though since others want to use ISP's name servers instead of our own for the subdomains.  

Thanks for your help James.